# Spread operator to merge object on import - AOT

Tags: angular, aot

I'm trying to provide an object which contains my translations keys and it's values.

example:

```
{ 
  "try_again_key": "Try Again", 
  "cancel_key": "Cancel",
  "other_key": "Other"
  ...
}
```

I have to import this object in my features module and provide it to a lib so that I can use translate from Angular but in my case, I need to merge 2 objects(both containing different translations keys) like this:

```
import { myFallback } from "../../locale/fallback-ts";
import { otherFallback} from "@company/platform-components";

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
        TranslationsModule.forChild([
        {
            domain: "domain",
            service: "service",
            fallback: { ...otherFallback, ...myFallback },
        },
    ]),
```

when I log the fallback on JIT = contains my 2 merged objects

when I log the fallback on AOT = empty object

```
import { myFallback } from "../../locale/fallback-ts";
import { otherFallback} from "@company/platform-components";
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
        TranslationsModule.forChild([
        {
            domain: "domain",
            service: "service",
            fallback: myFallback,
        },
    ]),
```

when I log the fallback on JIT/AOT = contains my object

but if I do like this, it works but than it doesn't help me because I won't be merging the objects, it seems spread operators is not supported by Angular AOT

some links I found about AOT: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler
in this link it doesn't specify I can't use with spread operator

this GitHub issue looks like what I need but it was ignored by angular team https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9511

my question is, am I doing something wrong? if it's a limitation from angular AOT, can I merge 2 objects another way?

Things I've tried:

using `Object.assign()` instead of spread operator.

declaring a const that receives this 2 objects and than importing it on my `.forChild()` method

`export const fallback = { ...tsValues, ...jsonValues};`

Comment: What is your actual error from the aot compiler? It may not be the spread operator but perhaps something in `otherFallback`. To test, does it compile properly when you do `fallback: otherFallback`?

Comment: yes, I can do fallback: otherfallback, actually i forgot to say, there is no error at all, the only thing is that on AOT my object is undefined, and in JIT is not.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28078), ngc, which is the compiler used on AOT, does not evaluate the spread operator in object literals while processing metadata by design, even though it evaluates spread in literal arrays (as [stated on the link you provided](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax-limitations) about the AOT compiler).

The good thing is that, apparently, this issue has already been fixed on ivy (the new Angular compilation and rendering pipeline), as [mentioned at the end of the issue above](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28078#issuecomment-454589881).